# Problems in refactoring code / figuring out the design pattern to use

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

So , I had quite a few lines of code to be executed in the main method of the Application (Main) class of a java project . To get rid of all the clutter , I ended up refactoring it using the extract method refactoring technique , but then I got a lot of static methods in the Main class which I'm not a fan of .... What would be a better way to get a clean main Application method ? Should I use a singleton class perhaps ?What other design pattern / technique should I use to avoid having all these static methods in my main class and keeping the main method as succinct as possible ?

**Initial Code :**

```
import controller.Statistics;
import model.primary.customer.CustomerInfo;
import model.primary.movie.MovieInfo;
import model.primary.rating.RatingInfo;
import util.FileParsing.FileParser;
import util.mapping.CustomerMapper;
import util.mapping.MovieMapper;
import util.mapping.RatingsMapper;
import view.DisplayStatistics;
import view.UserInterface;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Statistics statistics = processStatistics();
        DisplayStatistics displayStatistics = new DisplayStatistics(statistics);
        initiateUI(displayStatistics);
    }

    private static Statistics processStatistics() {
        MovieInfo movieInfo = processMovies();
        CustomerInfo customerInfo = processCustomers();
        RatingInfo ratingInfo = processRatings();

        return new Statistics(customerInfo, movieInfo, ratingInfo);
    }

    private static void initiateUI(DisplayStatistics displayStatistics) {
        UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface(displayStatistics);
        userInterface.start();
    }

    private static RatingInfo processRatings() {
        FileParser ratingsFile = new FileParser("ratings.dat", "::");
        RatingsMapper ratingsMapper = new RatingsMapper(ratingsFile, 4);
        return new RatingInfo(ratingsMapper.getCustomerIDMovieIDRatingAndTimeMap());
    }

    private static CustomerInfo processCustomers() {
        FileParser customerFile = new FileParser("users.dat", "::");
        CustomerMapper customerMapper = new CustomerMapper(customerFile, 5);
        return new CustomerInfo(customerMapper.getIdCustomerMap());
    }

    private static MovieInfo processMovies() {
        FileParser movieFile = new FileParser("movies.dat", "::");
        MovieMapper movieMapper = new MovieMapper(movieFile, 3);
        return new MovieInfo(movieMapper.getIdMovieMap());
    }

}
```

**Changed Code after using Singleton Class (Processor):**

```
import controller.Statistics;
import view.DisplayStatistics;
import view.UserInterface;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Statistics statistics = Processor.getInstance().processStatistics();

        DisplayStatistics displayStatistics = new DisplayStatistics(statistics);

        UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface(displayStatistics);

        userInterface.start();
    }


}
```

**Singleton Class (Processor) code :**

```
import controller.Statistics;
import model.primary.customer.CustomerInfo;
import model.primary.movie.MovieInfo;
import model.primary.rating.RatingInfo;
import util.FileParsing.FileParser;
import util.mapping.CustomerMapper;
import util.mapping.MovieMapper;
import util.mapping.RatingsMapper;


public class Processor {
    private static Processor ourInstance = new Processor();

    public static Processor getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private Processor() {

    }

    static Statistics processStatistics() {

        MovieInfo movieInfo = processMovies();
        CustomerInfo customerInfo = processCustomers();
        RatingInfo ratingInfo = processRatings();

        return new Statistics(customerInfo, movieInfo, ratingInfo);
    }

    private static RatingInfo processRatings() {

        FileParser ratingsFile = new FileParser("ratings.dat", "::");
        RatingsMapper ratingsMapper = new RatingsMapper(ratingsFile, 4);
        return new RatingInfo(ratingsMapper.getCustomerIDMovieIDRatingAndTimeMap());
    }

    private static CustomerInfo processCustomers() {

        FileParser customerFile = new FileParser("users.dat", "::");
        CustomerMapper customerMapper = new CustomerMapper(customerFile, 5);
        return new CustomerInfo(customerMapper.getIdCustomerMap());
    }

    private static MovieInfo processMovies() {

        FileParser movieFile = new FileParser("movies.dat", "::");
        MovieMapper movieMapper = new MovieMapper(movieFile, 3);
        return new MovieInfo(movieMapper.getIdMovieMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to judge your design because it's not clear how your app will be changed, especially your posted code is written in the root of the app (`main` method) where changes are welcomed.

In order to propose a better design, I suppose that:

1. The way to create `XXXInfo` will be changed, e.g. they can be loaded and processed from SQL database, network ...
2. The composing of `Statistics`, `DisplayStatistics`, and `UserInterface` happens somewhere in your app other than the `main` method, this means you may want to reuse this composing in another code.

So here is the code:

```
interface InfoLoader {
    RatingInfo loadRatingInfo();
    CustomerInfo loadCustomerInfo();
    MovieInfo loadMovieInfo();
}

class FileInfoLoader implements InfoLoader {
    public RatingInfo loadRatingInfo() {
        FileParser ratingsFile = new FileParser("ratings.dat", "::");
        RatingsMapper ratingsMapper = new RatingsMapper(ratingsFile, 4);
        return new RatingInfo(ratingsMapper.getCustomerIDMovieIDRatingAndTimeMap());
    }
    public CustomerInfo loadCustomerInfo () {
        FileParser customerFile = new FileParser("users.dat", "::");
        CustomerMapper customerMapper = new CustomerMapper(customerFile, 5);
        return new CustomerInfo(customerMapper.getIdCustomerMap());
    }
    public MovieInfo loadMovieInfo () {
        FileParser movieFile = new FileParser("movies.dat", "::");
        MovieMapper movieMapper = new MovieMapper(movieFile, 3);
        return new MovieInfo(movieMapper.getIdMovieMap());
    }
}

class App {
    public App(InfoLoader infoLoader) {
        this.infoLoader = infoLoader;
    }
    public void start() {
        Statistics stat = new Statistics(
            infoLoader.loadCustomerInfo(),
            infoLoader.loadMovieInfo(),
            infoLoader.loadRatingInfo()
        );
        DisplayStatistics ds = new DisplayStatistics(stat);
        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface(ds);
        ui.start();
    }
    private InfoLoader infoLoader;
}

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InfoLoader infoLoader = new FileInfoLoader();
        // or InfoLoader infoLoader = new SqlInfoLoader();
        App app = new App(infoLoader);
        app.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed !! Thanks !